# Set colors to group of nodes by attribute values in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I have three types of nodes (dynmanicallly drawn hundred or thousands of nodes)

1- Animals
2- Trees
3- Humans

I am reading values from JSON file and dynamically nodes are created with unknown values.

I want to color them by their type. so I assigned a `nodetype` property to identify.

Here is my node code for nodes.

```
G.add_node(HumanID, nodetype="red", UserName=userName)
G.add_node(TreeID, nodetype="green", BranchName=branchName)
G.add_node(AnimalID, nodetype="blue", AName=aName)
```

and to get the values

```
colors = set(nx.get_node_attributes(G,'nodetype').values())
print(colors)
```

output: `{'green', 'red', 'blue'}`

I  know this is not right but I want something like this

```
nx.draw(G,  node_color= colors)
```

so it should draw nodes with 3 different colors. I tried multiple ways to do so but since I am new with `Networkx` and `Matplotlib` so no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When coloring graphs using `nx.draw` it is key to **keep the order of `colors` the same as the nodes order**.
So using a set won't do since these are unordered and do not allow duplicate values.

Instead what you want is, from the [`nx.draw_networkx` documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx):

> node_color (color or array of colors (default=’#1f78b4’)) – Node color. Can be a single color or ***a sequence of colors with the same length as nodelist***. Color can be string, or rgb (or rgba) tuple of floats from 0-1. If numeric values are specified they will be mapped to colors using the cmap and vmin,vmax parameters. See matplotlib.scatter for more details.

So if we consider a list, we can obtain `colors` like this:

```py
colors = [u[1] for u in G.nodes(data="nodetype")]
```

#### Here is an example:

```py
G=nx.Graph()

G.add_node(1, nodetype="red")
G.add_node(2, nodetype="blue")
G.add_node(3, nodetype="green")
G.add_node(4, nodetype="red")
G.add_edge(1, 3)
G.add_edge(2, 4)
G.add_edge(2, 3)

colors = [u[1] for u in G.nodes(data="nodetype")]
nx.draw(G, with_labels =True, node_color = colors)
```

Draws:
[image: Example Result]

---

EDIT:

### One thing that may cause the issue you're having:

Adding a node with `nodetype="not_a_color"`:

```
G.add_node(4, nodetype="not_a_color")
colors = [u[1] for u in G.nodes(data="nodetype")]
nx.draw(G, with_labels =True, node_color = colors)
```

This gives the same error that you're getting:

> ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'not_a_color']

Of course that if you have a long list it is more difficult to check.
Try running the following, to check if there is a color that is neither `"red"`,`"green"` or `"blue"`

```
colors = [u[1] for u in G.nodes(data="nodetype")]

not_colors = [c for c in colors if c not in ("red", "green", "blue")]
if not_colors:
    print("TEST FAILED:", not_colors)
```

If you have `None` in any of your node's `node_type` attribute, this will print those nodes in black:

```
#(change *colors* to):

colors = []
for u in G.nodes(data="nodetype"):
    if u[1] in ("red", "green", "blue"):
        colors.append(u[1])
    elif u[1] == None:
        colors.append("black")
    else:
        #do something?
        print("ERROR: Should be red, green, blue or None")
```

Comment: we are passing list to graph here node_color = colors. this is not right. i already tried this. here is error of your code. ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green'.... its a long list.

Comment: it's supposed to work, since it is a `sequence of colors`

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer please try running the code as is and then adapt it to you code

Comment: There are a lot of None at the end of list. so this maybe the problem? I think I am having a lot of nodes with none values. let me first clear this problem. this I test this solution.

Comment: that is the problem! I will post a code to print those in *black*

Comment: there you go! check the last edit and see if it works ;)